# threejs blend json export + Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js, blender

I try to render in Chrome browser the default 3D cube template loaded by Blender v2.74 when you open a new project.
I've exported this as json using the threejs v1.4.0 add-on.
I'm using Three.js revision 71.

Referring to the following documentation I try to load this json model currently stored in a database. (http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader)

Everything seems fine but it fails with the following errors :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transparent' of undefined

The json generated is :

```
{
    "faces": [33,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,33,4,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,33,0,4,5,1,0,4,7,1,33,1,5,6,2,1,7,6,2,33,2,6,7,3,2,6,5,3,33,4,0,3,7,4,0,3,5],
    "name": "CubeGeometry",
    "metadata": {
        "faces": 6,
        "uvs": 0,
        "normals": 8,
        "type": "Geometry",
        "vertices": 8,
        "generator": "io_three",
        "version": 3
    },
    "normals": [0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],
    "vertices": [1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
    "uvs": []
}
```

The code uses to load the json is :

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 5;

// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
   $scope.parentScope.apiRootUrl + "/" + $scope.selectedItem.model3D,
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function (geometry, materials) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
        var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(object);
    }
);

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON model is properly loaded after your init() method and when window.requestAnimationFrame( update ) is called it get's updated and your errors are gone.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,
I probably miss something. Not sure about which init() you are talking about.

Comment: I've just added the json and the javascript code I uses.